# Auto Click button on a page I don't own

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is more of a theory question. I would like to create a button on my own page, that when pressed, will go to the desired destination URL, auto-click a button on that destination URL (that I don't own), and do some sort of action with resulting auto-button-click.

Example: Say there is a site (that I don't own) that has information that is only revealed through a button click, like a search engine or wiki page search buttons. I make my own page that the user clicks my button, and my page opens the new URL tab, and auto-clicks the button on the destination URL.

Is this possible?

Comment: No. That is not possible. If however the click is calling the backend and the backend allows you to perform the same call (API / CORS) then you could in principle show the same data on your page. On YOUR  SERVER you can better call that backend, but do think about permissioins

Comment: If you wanted to make it possible, you'd need authentication from the client and some method of control. Firefox/Chrome plugins may give you that

Comment: Yes, but not to show the result of that URL on your own page unless you load the url via a proxy on your server or use an iframe

Comment: @that guy yes it is enough information, sounds like a simple curl request to the url which the clicking of the button is supposed to lead to, perhaps with some url parameters as variables? Definitely look into using curl.

Comment: I imagine the destination URL im trying to auto-click will have some backend functions that I wont have access too, so I dont think I can just copy the destination URL from the third-party site.. sorry I deleted my comment regarding that angle

Comment: can you access the URL from your browser without being an authenticated user, just by clicking that button?

Comment: thanks for the link of the duplicate. I tried to search this question many ways, and of course didnt come up with that duplicate. Thanks for your answers